# robot_state_publisher, for gazebo only or for actual robot?

Tags: robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

The robot_state_publisher publishes transform (which is usually based on the URDF file specified).
But when we are talking about the URDF file, we are usually talking about Gazebo, which is for simulation.

Ok. But if I want to do ACTUAL physical robot, do I still need to use robot_state_publisher to publishes transform? I am confused.  If robot_state_publisher still publishes transform, what happen to the PHYSICAL base driver of the robot? From what I know, the base driver publishes odometry and transform as well. I am very confused.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216257/robot_state_publisher,--for-gazebo-only-or-for-actual-robot?/) by [kuku123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22953/kuku123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

URDF is not only for Gazebo, or just for simulation purposes. URDF defines your robot's physical dimensions, joints, constraints etc. Therefore `robot_state_publisher` publishes states of your link in your robot, not necessarily in simulation. For example, also for actual robot, it publishes `tf` data between your `base_link` and laser sensor link (like `base_laser_link`) using distances defined in URDF. You do not need to publish them separately by writing some nodes.

For joint states, if you can publish the states of your joints to `joint_states` topic, it can also publish those, not only static link distances.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4